# Script task in SSIS package is executing but not performing the action

Tags: sql-server, ssis, script-task

I have the two SSIS packages which basically has two action like below

[image]

First it truncates the contents of the table and then it executes the script task like basically call an API and inserts the response in to the table

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {   
        public async void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var sqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
                ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["SurplusMouse_ADONET"];

                string serviceUrl = Dts.Variables["$Project::RM_ServiceUrl"].Value.ToString();
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string APIUrl = string.Format(serviceUrl + "/gonogo");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(APIUrl);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    try
                    {
                        sqlConn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);

                        const string query = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[RM_Approved_Room_State]
                                          (APPROVED_ROOM_STATEID,SOURCE_ROOMID,DEST_ROOMID,ENTITY_TYPEID)
                                           SELECT id, sourceRoomRefId, destinationRoomRefId,entityRefId
                                           FROM OPENJSON(@json)
                                           WITH (
                                                 id int,
                                                 sourceRoomRefId int,
                                                 destinationRoomRefId int,
                                                 entityRefId int
                                                 ) j;";
                        using (var sqlCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
                        {
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@json", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = result;
                            await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (sqlConn != null)
                            cm.ReleaseConnection(sqlConn);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }

        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion    
    } }
```

Similar to the above package I have another one which does more likely does insert records into different table the response from a different endpoint. When I execute the packages locally/ execute them separately after deploying it in to the server it works fine. But when I add them in to the SQL Server Agent Job like below and run them on a schedule

[image]

The Jobs run successfully and dont show any errors but I can see only one table with data from one package but the other one truncates the records but I dont think the script task is getting executed / I dont see any records inserted. I dont think there are any issues with access because when I run them seperate manually the data are getting inserted, Just when it is running on a schedule it is not working as expected. Any idea what could be happening here.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You could add events to the script (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/raising-events-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-ver15) and see from the log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/monitor-running-packages-and-other-operations?view=sql-server-ver15#reports) whether the task is really executed and does it failt at some point

Comment: I feel like I've seen other people try and fail to have `async` calls in scripts.

Comment: @billinkc Thank you Do you have any recommendation on resolving the issue.. I am new the scripts any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: you should be able to debug the script when running it VS, I see that you have the red dot on the object so you've added in breakpoints, does VS not start the debugger?